# Array formula SUMIF values with row and column conditions

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

I'm trying to use an array formula to automatically expand and sum a range conditional on the values in both the columns and rows.

E.g. The formula would automatically expand and sum a range based on `Foo` and `1` as the conditions for the SUMIF, then for `Bar` and `1` for the next conditionals on SUMIF, and so on.

Example:

```
    Foo    Bar    Baz    
1   10     20
2   10      
3
```

Sample data range:

```
Amount ID Name
10     1 Foo
10     2 Foo
20     1 Bar
```

I've looked at answers [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/KKDRjZlfvWA/QPh-s-9LDmYJ) But I think I'm missing something with how the formula is built. I feel like I need to use a transpose to remove having to deal with having rows and columns evaluated.

I can do this with a simple SUMIF() however, the data is dynamic so having an array formula will stop having to reassign the ranges every time the data updates.

Comment: I'm thinking that as well .. I've found some other posts with pivot tables as the answer so I'm going to try that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP seems amenable to other solutions so here is a pivot table. The style is new and like Excel drilldown is possible but seemingly the ordering of columns at least is not as flexible as Excel:

[image: WA47823374 example]

Expansion can be allowed for by extending the range but blank rows will add a blank row (with `0`s where relevant) into the pivot table, until all are populated.

I copied the pivot table into the same sheet as the data for the sake of the image. If expansion is required (eg more rows in the pivot table) a `#REF!` error may be encountered if the pivot table has been copied and into a space not large enough to accommodate the new size.